# Not getting required result from if else in helper method

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, if-statement, helper

I have used the helper for displaying background color for holidays and leaves and I'm calling the helper method from view like this -

```
%th{:class => weekend_class_top(date)}= date.strftime("%d")
```

helper method which has been called -

```
def weekend_class_top(date)
    if (date == date.end_of_month)
      'weekend_color5'
    elsif (date.to_s(:weekend) == 'Sun')  
      'weekend_color3'
    elsif @holidays.any?
      @holidays.map.each do |holiday|
        if (date == holiday)
          'timesheet_holiday_color'
        end
      end
    elsif @user_leaves.any?
      @user_leaves.flatten.map.each do |leave|
        if (date == leave)
          'timesheet_leave_color'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

the code that I have written, I'm getting background color only for holidays not leaves even though both holidays and leaves are present.

This is edited helper method -

```
def weekend_class_top(date)
    if (date == date.end_of_month)
      'weekend_color5'
    elsif (date.to_s(:weekend) == 'Sun')  
      'weekend_color3'
    elsif @holidays.any?
      @holidays.map.each do |holiday|
        if @user_leaves.any?
          @user_leaves.flatten.map.each do |leave|
            if (date == leave)
              'timesheet_leave_color'
            end
          end
        elsif (date == holiday)
          'timesheet_holiday_color'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Through the above written methd I'm only getting the background color for leaves but *not for holidays*.

Comment: Probably variables `@holidays` and `@user_leaves` are undefined. Try to debug you code.

Comment: both of them are present I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got the correct result -

```
def weekend_class_top(date)
    if (date == date.end_of_month)
      'weekend_color5'
    elsif (date.to_s(:weekend) == 'Sun')  
      'weekend_color3'
    elsif @holidays.include?(date)
      'timesheet_holiday_color'
    elsif @user_leaves.flatten.include?(date)
      'timesheet_leave_color'
    end
  end
```